# C++ friend function can't access private members

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

This is supposed to be a string class with a bunch of operators and functions, including two friend functions. And those two cause some trouble for me, because the compiler says that they can not access the private members. Here is my string.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef STR_H
#define STR_H

namespace MyStr
{
class Str
{
private:
    unsigned int length;
    char *data;
public:
    Str();
    Str(const Str&);
    Str(const char*);
    Str(char c, unsigned int db);
    ~Str();
    char* cStr() const;
    unsigned int getLength() const;
```

lots of irrevelant functions here...

```
    friend int operator/ (const Str&, char);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Str&);
};
}
#endif /* STR_H */
```

here is the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Str.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace MyStr;

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,const Str& str)
{
    for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    {
        out<<str.data[i];
    }
    out<<endl;
    return out;
}

int operator/ (const Str& str, char c)
{
    for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    {
        if(str.data[i]==c) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This code won't compile, the compiler claiming that the `Str` members are private.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: error: 'char* MyStr::Str::data' is private|
error: 'unsigned int MyStr::Str::length' is private|

Comment: On what line is it emitting that error? Is it for both functions?

Comment: Str.h|10|error: 'unsigned int MyStr::Str::length' is private|

both functions. these errors occour when the functions tries to acces the private members, like this: i<str.length
that line emits the error I quoted upper.

Comment: Your definition and declaration of the friend functions are in different namespaces.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should pay more attention to namespaces.

```
class Str {
private:
    unsigned int length;
    char *data;
public:
    Str(){}
    Str(const Str&){}
    Str(const char*){}
    Str(char c, unsigned int db){}
    // maybe something more...
    friend int operator/ (const Str&, char);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Str&);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,const Str& str)
{
    for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        out<<str.data[i];
    out<<endl;
    return out;
}

int operator/ (const Str& str, char c)
{
    for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        if(str.data[i]==c) return i;

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    Str s;
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

You get error because of the unmatched namespaces. If you prefer to stick with `MyStr` then you should add namespace `MyStr` to overloaded *friend* operators. This is how you can do it: (operators should be defined within namespace `MyStr`)

```
namespace MyStr {  
    ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,const Str& str)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        {
             out<<str.data[i];
         }
        out<<endl;
        return out;
    }

    int operator/ (const Str& str, char c)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        {
            if(str.data[i]==c) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When you declare the friend functions inside `Str` they are considered to be in the immediately enclosing namespace, `MyStr`.

The operators you define are in the global namespace, so the compiler believes that those are two entirely different operators, and not the friends.

You can solve this by adding

```
namespace MyStr
{

}
```

around the operators in the .cpp file.

Comment: I'm trying this and it's not working -- http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$3217

Comment: @David - That's different. You try to access `s.x` inside main, and main isn't a friend of the class.