# Friend function not allowed to access private member

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

I thought friend functions had access to all members. Even in this question it worked:
    [C++ friend function can't access private members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731414/c-friend-function-cant-access-private-members)

The answer given in that question seems identical to my code, and his compiled fine while mine just says array_ is pivate. Anyone know why?

.h:

```
#ifndef matrix_h
#define matrix_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Comparable>
class matrix
{
    private:
        size_t num_cols_;
        size_t num_rows_;
        Comparable **array_;

    public:
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
        size_t NumRows();
        size_t NumCols();
};
#endif
```

.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename Comparable>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, matrix<Comparable> & rhs){
    size_t c = rhs.NumRows();
    size_t d = rhs.NumCols();
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            o << rhs.array_[i][j];         //not allowed
        }
        o << endl;
    }
    return o;
}

template <typename Comparable>
size_t matrix<Comparable>::NumRows(){
    return num_rows_;
}

template <typename Comparable>
size_t matrix<Comparable>::NumCols(){
    return num_cols_;
}


int main(){
    matrix<int> a;
    cout << a << endl;

}
```

Comment: You've declared the friend function to take a `const matrix<Comparable> &`, but its definition takes a `matrix<Comparable> &`. They aren't the same function.

Comment: Also: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: If I make them both const, or remove const than I get an undefined reference error. Undefined reference to operator<<

Comment: Danger: [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation. Your matrix will have unfortunate and probably fatal behaviour if copied or moved.

Comment: I have a constructor/destructor/copy overload. I just didn't include it since it's irrelevant. Also am I not supposed to use a .cpp?

Comment: In order for a template to work, everyone using the template needs to be able to see the functions they need to specialize. If they in the header, that's no problem. If they are in a CPP file... Including the CPP file is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you use `const` in both places and add `const` to the declarations of `numRows` and `numCols` too. Then what's the problem? Well...

You think it's identical, but your code has a template. And the friend declaration

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
```

is not a template, so it doesn't match the definition

```
template <typename Comparable>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, matrix<Comparable> & rhs){ // ...
```

which *is* a template. In fact gcc will give a warning:

```
matrix.h:16:79: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const matrix<Comparable>&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
         friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
                                                                               ^
matrix.h:16:79: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
```

It's tempting to just friend all specializations, like this:

```
template <typename T>
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<T> & rhs);
```

Unfortunately, this won't work for the reasons explained here: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) You'll be able to compile `matrix.cpp`, but not a separate driver program, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    matrix<int> m;
    cout << m << endl;
}
```

You get an undefined reference error. Instead, you really should just define your entire matrix class in the header and ditch the .cpp file.

It should be pointed out that this still has a problem: you can call this `operator<<` just fine, but you can't, say, take its address, because it can only be found by argument-dependent lookup.

```
auto ptr = static_cast<ostream&(*)(ostream&, const matrix<int>&)>(operator<<); // error
```

For it to be found by unqualified lookup, it must have a matching declaration at namespace scope. And it is actually impossible to write such a declaration (the syntax of C++ doesn't have any way to do it)! To fix this, we need to turn `operator<<` into a function template, defined inline:

```
template <typename Comparable>
class matrix {
    // ...
    template <typename T>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const matrix<T>& rhs) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
// namespace-scope declaration
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const matrix<T>& rhs);
```

Now the above code taking the address of the operator will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. The compiler complains because the function you implement is different with the one you declare(in declaration rhs is decorated by const, in implementation it isn't).
2. After you add const in implementation, the compiler complains "Undefined reference" because the declaration and the implementation is still not the same. The implementation is a template function, the decalartion is not.

   ```
   #ifndef matrix_h
   #define matrix_h

   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   template <typename Comparable>
   class matrix
   {
       private:
           size_t num_cols_;
           size_t num_rows_;
           Comparable **array_;

       public:
           template<typename T>
           friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<T> & rhs);
           size_t NumRows() const;
           size_t NumCols() const;
   };

   template <typename Comparable>
   ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<Comparable> & rhs){
       size_t c = rhs.NumRows();
       size_t d = rhs.NumCols();
       for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
               o << rhs.array_[i][j];         //not allowed
           }
           o << endl;
       }
       return o;
   }

   template <typename Comparable>
   size_t matrix<Comparable>::NumRows() const{
       return num_rows_;
   }

   template <typename Comparable>
   size_t matrix<Comparable>::NumCols() const{
       return num_cols_;
   }

   #endif
   ```